# JSTL: What is the point?

Tags: jstl

I've been making JSPs for years by doing all of my work in classes and using a minimum amount of Java code on the JSP to retrieve the results and sometimes conditionally render content.

I'm looking to spruce up my game and I've been looking at using/learning more of the JSTL.

My big questions is why bother?  What is the point of JSTL tags?

For example, there are tags to do database queries on the JSP, which IMHO, violates the deservedly haloed principle of MVC separation.

I don't see any advantage for using a tag for a conditional versus just putting the code for the conditional in a

```
<% ... %>
```

Maybe if it is a large site, with a dedicated web designer who feels less intimidated by tags?

As far as iteration goes, my preference is to do that in a "view" class and just pull the finished string out on the JSP in between the static HTML tags ( i.e. pulling table rows out of a class onto a JSP between table tags on the JSP, that are hooked into CSS ).

I don't mean to sound disrespectful or ignorant.  I am legitimately curious.   What is the advantage of using JSTL?

Answer (score 2):

Because it is easier and faster to do something like

```
<fmt:message key="translation.key"/>
```

instead of to load ResourceBundles every time manually.

And you can use custom tags like

```
<mytags:security hasRole="ADMIN">
     content for the admin
     <mytags:customButton key="value"/>   
</mytags:security>
```

You do not need a "view" class. The JSP is the "view"

Answer (score 0):

> doing all of my work in classes

I believe this was precisely the (good or bad) idea behind JSTL: give the ability to people in charge of the presentation layer to do things quickly/easily without going to deep on the server side.